# Get one value of an own datatype

Tags: haskell, types

I have a own created datatype. It looks like:

```
data Message = Message {
_timeStamp :: Integer,
_userName :: String,
_messageContent :: String}
```

Now I want to get access for example to the username of a message. I tried a lot but it didn't work yet. Someone have a tip for me?

And: What are these { } for? Never saw that in Haskell before..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{}` denote record syntax which create a (named) field and accessor functions like this:

```
_timeStamp :: Message -> Integer
_userName :: Message -> String
_messageContent :: Message -> String
```

To access a field just type the field name and the message, like this:

```
m = Message 0 "ThreeFx" "Hey there!"
print (_userName m) --prints "ThreeFx"
```

Record syntax helps you in a way that you automatically have functions for accessing the time stamp for example and that you do not have to explicitly type every one:

```
timeStamp (Message t _ _) = t
userName (Message _ u _) = u
messageContent (Message _ _ c) = c
```

For more information look [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax).